# Websites show different EPS numbers

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, starting-out-investing, earnings-per-share

I'm a newbie here. This is my first post. I would appreciate it if someone will help me. I'm a bit confused about EPS values.

For example, Nvidia's Oct 2020 earnings:

- TradingView shows:

  EPS Est. 2.58 vs Actual 2.12, -17.75% surprise

  [image: screenshot]
- [Nasdaq](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/nvda/earnings) shows:

  EPS Est. 1.92 vs Actual 2.41, +25.52% surprise

  [image: screenshot]
- [MarketWatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/nvda/analystestimates) shows:

  EPS Est. 2.91 vs Actual 2.91, +0.00% surprise

  [image: screenshot]
- [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NVDA/analysis?p=NVDA) shows:

  EPS Est. 2.57 vs Actual 2.91, +13.20% surprise

  [image: screenshot]

Why do these differences occur?
Which numbers do you think I should trust?
Can someone explain to me?

Comment: There's something weird about the MarketWatch table. It gives you the "actual EPS" for the *future* (Q1 2021, Q2 2021, Q3 2021).

Comment: @Flux NVIDIA'a fiscal year ends in January (rather then December), so the "quarters" end 11 months ahead of the calendar quarter (meaning that 3Q2021 ended on Oct 25, 2020)

Comment: Did you have to pay to get the TradingView chart with earnings information (as shown in your screenshot)?

Comment: I have Pro+ account but I have no idea free account has this feature.

Answer (score 2):

NVIDIA [reported](https://nvidianews.nvidia.com/news/nvidia-announces-financial-results-for-third-quarter-fiscal-2021) both GAAP (Generally Accepted Accounting Principles) and non-GAAP earnings amounts at the end of their Q3. Their GAAP EPS was 2.12, but their non-GAAP EPS was 2.91. Different sites apparently use different values.

I can't reconcile the values that Nasdaq uses.  It's possible that their data hasn't fully incorporated the reported results since they were just announced a day ago. If you look at the Financials section their Q3 results aren't posted there yet.

Non-GAAP results are typically adjusted to remove the effect on non-recurring events, so that results from one period to the next are comparable.

Whether you use the GAAP or non-GAAP results depending on what you're trying to measure. For example, if you're trying to measure financial growth, non-GAAP might give you a sense of how their actual operations are growing.  You obviously can't just ignore the items that are excluded in non-GAAP results, but you might look at both depending on what you're evaluating.

Comment: Ty for very useful answer? Where can I find NVIDA's GAAP & Non-GAAP result? I'd like to check them on official statement. How about the differences on analysts estimate? Should I choose single site to keep tracking earnings result?